# MIME Type 'application/octet-stream' is switched to 'text/html' in my server. How to prevent?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying to download my .mp3 file from server but when I pass below code , it prints the file at browser screen in binary converting **Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8**.

If I tried same code to other server, It runs successfully with **Content-Type: application/octet-stream**. So I can say code is 100% valid (code is in **PHP**).

So Is this problem in server configuration or any other issue? Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);
$url = 'https://abcdefgh.s3.amazonaws.com/audio/1431428586_z3PtL.mp3';
$file = basename($url);
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Do you download .mp3 directly or through a .php script?

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: Yes , I am using PHP code

Answer (score 0):

yes, it could be the server configuration. firstly, try to upload your original mp3 to the server and access it like http://yourserver.com/file.mp3.
If you can, then something wrong with your php, if you cannot - tweak the server.

Comment: Yes, as ur guidence, I did the same. But I wasnt able to do correctly.

Comment: and yes, My php code is correct as i can run it successfully in other server.

Comment: so tweak the server or use another one, maybe it's restricted to server mp3, which is very common practice

Comment: Yes, but this is not the solution to switch server. I must use that server.

Comment: what level of access do you have? can change the config files? what kind of server is that? apache, nginx?

Comment: Its apache server, having all access.

Comment: check your mime.types file and see if there  is  
audio/mpeg          mpga mp2 mp3

Comment: yes checked. Have this.
audio/mpeg mpga mpega mp2 mp3 m4a

Comment: so what exactly happens when you try to download actual mp3 file?

Comment: It prints binary form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80460/discussion-between-vitr-and-ronakp).